# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Every time I open a certain page in my app it gives me error  `Can't perform a react state on an unmounted component, it indicates a memory leak..` how can i fix that? the page is a profile page i fetch the user data and the posts, it contains a React Native Tab View, here's how i fetch the data

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const { currentUser, posts } = props;

    if (props.route.params.uid === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
      setUser(currentUser);
      setUserPosts([]);
    } else {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(props.route.params.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists) {
            setUser(snapshot.data());
          } else {
            console.log('does not exist');
          }
        });
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(props.route.params.uid)
        .collection('userPosts')
        .orderBy('creation', 'desc')
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          let posts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data();
            const id = doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          });
          setUserPosts(posts);
        });
    }
    if (props.following.indexOf(props.route.params.uid) > -1) {
      setFollowing(true);
    } else {
      setFollowing(false);
    }
  }, [props.route.params.uid, props.following]);
```

Comment: any solutions???